# insert into oracle from yii2 data type number

Tags: yii2

yii2 I use with Oracle and have a field in the database of type number but when I want to store it, do not save the decimal values
 Example:
 $model->CLASIF_BUEN_ESTADO = 0.05 saves 0
 $model->CLASIF_BUEN_ESTADO = 1.05 saves 1

Try and save it as text $model->CLASIF_BUEN_ESTADO = "0.05" saves 0
and coma stores $model->CLASIF_BUEN_ESTADO = "0,05" saves null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you did set precision without the scale for this column type in the database.

Some examples for input value = **1234567.89**

For `column_name NUMBER` is stored as **1234567.89**
For `column_name NUMBER (9)` is stored as **1234568**
For `column_name NUMBER (9, 2)` is stored as **1234567.89**
For `column_name NUMBER (9, 1)` is stored as **1234567.9**

First brackets value is precision, second is scale.